# ng-repeat li have extra line after each repetition

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I use the angular `ng-repeat` directive with an `<li>` element, I get an extra line after each `<li>`. Simple example with pictures below.

Simple example using angular `ng-repeat` directive:

```
<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat = "num in [0,1,2,3,4]">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">{{num}}</li>
</ul>
```

Will create something like : 
[image]

However doing it without angular `ng-repeat` such as

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">3</li>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">4A</li>
</ul>
```

results in [image]

As you can tell, when I use the `ng-repeat` directive, I get an extra line below each repeated element. Is there a subtlety that I am missing or does anyone know how to remove the extra line?

Comment: Can you provide a plunker for your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're repeating your `<ul>` element in your current markup. The visual difference is because you are essentially rendering something like this...

```
<ul>
    <li>0</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
...
```

Instead, change to the following and `ng-repeat` your `<li>`

```
<ul class="list-group" >
    <li ng-repeat="num in [0,1,2,3,4]" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">{{num}}</li>
</ul>
```